# Typedef struct cannot be cast to pointer

Tags: c, struct

I've seen this question in multiple posts but I have yet to find one that has a good explanation for me. Im trying to create a linked list but the struct nor the functions cant be called without getting the error cannot cast to a pointer. Its really bugging me. Any help would be appreciated on how to get this working right. Heres some of the code below thats the issue.

```
typedef struct node
{
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *head = NULL;

node* create(void *data, node *next)
{
    node *new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        exit(0);
    }else{

        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = next;
        return new_node;
    }

}

node* prepend(node *head, void *data)
{
    node *new_node = create(data,head);
    head = new_node;
    return head;
}


void preload_adz(int adz_fd)
{
    struct adz adz_info;
    char adz_data[40];
    char adz_text[38];
    int adz_delay;
    char adz_delayS[2];

    read(adz_fd,adz_data,40);
    strncpy(adz_text,adz_data + 2,40-2);
    sprintf(adz_delayS, "%c%c",adz_data[0],adz_data[1]);
    adz_delay = atoi(adz_delayS);

    adz_info.delay = adz_delay;
    strncpy(adz_info.text,adz_text,38);

    head = prepend(head, (void*)adz_info); //<---This line throws the error

    while(read(adz_fd,adz_data,40) > 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't cast a struct to be a pointer. What exactly are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: im trying to start the linked list, was following some tutorial and that's exactly how it was done in the tutorial :/  http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-linked-list/#C_Linked_List_Program <-- Dats the tutorial

Comment: `(void*)adz_info` --> `&adz_info` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY This was the issue. lol. I dumb.

Comment: hey you `exit(0)` when malloc fails seriously

Comment: incorrect use of `strncpy`

Comment: Which book are you reading? Also, next time you ask such a question based on an error message, **please quote the precise error message**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct adz adz_info;

...

head = prepend(head, (void*)adz_info); //<---This line throws the error
```

The problem here is `adz_info` is not a pointer, it's the actual struct on the stack. Passing `adz_info` into a function will *copy* the struct.

You need a pointer to that struct. Use `&` to get its address. Once you have the pointer, you don't need to cast it to void pointer, that cast is automatic.

```
head = prepend(head, &adz_info);
```

Note that casting is a bookkeeping thing. Casting to `void *` doesn't turn a struct into a pointer, it says "compiler, ignore the declared type of this variable and just trust me that this is a void pointer".

Comment: This did it. *facepalm*

Comment: @WizKiz What M.M is talking about, I think, is since `adz_info` is allocated on the stack, its memory will be automatically garbage collected when `preload_adz` returns. Since it's being attached to the global `head`, that will leave `head` pointing at a deallocated chunk of memory; [a dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). You'll have to use heap memory, `malloc`.

Comment: It's not *allocated*; the C standard has a *very specific* definition of "allocated" described in [C11/6.2.4p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p1). Additionally, the C standard has *no definition* of *the stack*. What you probably meant is *that object <strike>with automatic storage duration</strike> can't be cast to a pointer* (see [C11/6.2.4p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p5) for a definition of "automatic storage duration", and also note that storage duration is mostly irrelevant to the solution, thus my <strike>strike</strike>).

Comment: @Seb C standard terminology differs from common jargon in a few areas ... it's common to say "allocated" to mean what the standard describes as *storage* , with "dynamic allocation" meaning what the standard calls *allocated*.  IMO it would be a losing cause to try and convert everyone in this case